# How to find which date range a date is in?

Tags: r, date, loops

I have a dataframe that holds the id and launch dates, and for each one I want to know which date range (Time_Seq) each launch date is in.

The vector of dates looks like:

```
data:
    ID     LAUNCH_DATE
1 50314486  2004-01-01
2 55842774  2004-01-27
```

and I have a time sequence dataframe that holds the different data ranges:

```
head(Time_Table):
  Time_Seq   DateFrom     DateTo
1      726 2003-12-29 2004-01-04
2      727 2004-01-05 2004-01-11
3      728 2004-01-12 2004-01-18
4      729 2004-01-19 2004-01-25
5      730 2004-01-26 2004-02-01
6      731 2004-02-02 2004-02-08
```

Ideally I would like the output to look like:

```
    ID     LAUNCH_DATE   Time_Seq
1 50314486  2004-01-01      726
2 55842774  2004-01-27      731
```

Currently I can work it out for one date in a very longhand what by doing:

```
Time_Table$Time_Seq[which( (date$LAUNCH_DATE[1]>=Time_Table$DATEFROM)&(date$LAUNCH_DATE[1]<=Time_Table$DATETO) )]
```

Can anyone suggest a simpler way without having to loop in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cut` function for cutting continuous variables up into categories works for dates.

```
data$Time_Seq <- cut(
  data$LAUNCH_DATE, 
  c(Time_Table$DateFrom, Time_Table$DateTo[nrow(Time_Table)]), 
  labels = Time_Table$Time_Seq,
  right = FALSE
)
```

Comment: That worked very well, thank you @RichieCotton. The only addition I would add is that I needed to add an extra date to Time_Table$DateFrom, which is needed to close the final Time_Seq.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to play around with `interval` and `%within%` in package `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)

# create intervals
interval <- with(Time_Table, new_interval(ymd(DateFrom), ymd(DateTo)))

# for each LAUNCH_DATE, test whether it falls within an interval, and pick corresponding Time_Seq
data$Time_Seq <- sapply(data$LAUNCH_DATE, function(x) Time_Table$Time_Seq[ymd(x) %within% interval])
```